# CC Emails for address@customdomain.com to the super admin when using Google Apps for business?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace

I have Google Apps for business email set up for a custom domain. There is a super admin and a couple of users. Whenever any of the users receive an email, I want the super admin to receive it as well. Just how we cc when sending emails.

I apologize if this is a duplicate question, but I did not find a satisfactory answer!

Any guidance on how to do this?

Comment: That would not be officially supported of-course! What you are looking for is a total breach of privacy.

Comment: @AbhishekGirish Since the Admin wants to see all the mails of a domain user then he/she must be able to. This is not a security breach of privacy, but this is the need of Organization, and an Organization must have full control over its resources. Either it is the mail of an employee or a document or anything else which comes under the T&Cs of the Organization

Comment: +1 with @WaqarAhmad... If I were to do this for the user's personal mails, then it was a security breach! If I'm the owner of the company, I should know that the email address is being used for company matters only!

Comment: I think Google Vault (Postini) is gathering all e-mails, available for admins.

Comment: Any news? Can you give us an update?

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra Since its not possible via straight forward means, we decided to create the passwords for the user accounts ourselves and asked them not to change it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are Super admin who want to check the emails being received by domain users, You should create Email Monitors using Mail Audit API. I have been successful to do this using Google Apps Script and Email Audit API. Hope this will come to rescue you too.

Comment: I never could give the time for it, would be nice if you point me to a tutorial of some sort. But thanks anyways for introducing me to something new! :D